# Import Facebook SDK for Android Studio 0.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

The Project Structure dialog in 0.3.1 has changed completely - I cannot figure out how to import the Facebook SDK using the new structure. Facebook's import instructions has not been updated. If anyone coul provide assistance please that would be much appreciated.

Update: Screenshot of errors after applying @plastiv's suggestion

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit next file and re-sync project (Sync project with gradle files button or restart idea).

`MyProject\MyApp\build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook:3.5.2'
}
```

As you can see this is not official @aar library bundle, until Facebook uploads its SDK to mavenCentral we can use this temp solution from the community.

Comment: Little question. If the repo says version 3.0.2, how do you know that the last version is 3.5.2? (That is something I need to learn yet).

Comment: That page is outdated and thats confusing, i see. I updated the answer to use different repo, which pays more attention to keep docs updated. Latest version can be checked with facebook itselft here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk or here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Comment: I see, Would be good to have a way to know which version is the last without having to search in the official pages. Anyway, this wasn't my question, but I upvote you. Thanks.

Comment: You can use dynamic version. Like `3.5.+` or even `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook:+'` and gradle will search for the latest one automatically.

Comment: @plastiv Please see the question for a screenshot of the errors I get if applying your suggestion

Comment: At this moment, the last version from facebook is 3.7
In the repo, last version available is 3.6, so the dependencie would be `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook:3.6' ` For me the best is to use dynamic version as plastiv said

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 'Android support repository' from Android SDK manager

Comment: The SDK Manager shows a wide range of updates. Is it safe to install? I've had many issues with updates to Android Studio resulting in the project failing to compile without manual fixes to build files

Comment: No one force you update everything. Un-check all updates and install only repository.