# Android studio 0.3.2 for OS X - import module

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following this guide

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/

but i'm stuck on the first step. It seems that with the latest version of android studio there's no more import module function. It was supposed to be under file -> project structure -> click on +. If I follow this step I haven't and import option, only one to create a new module.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831230/import-facebook-sdk-for-android-studio-0-3-1/19834642#19834642

Comment: @plastiv how did you generate the aar file for Facebook sdk?

Comment: If you build library project with `android-library` gradle plugin the result will be as @aar bundle.

Comment: So i have to import the Facebook library project in android studio and then build it. The result will be an aar bundle. Is it right? Then if i want to use it i can import the war in the project and manage it as a jar. Is it correct?

Comment: Import facebookSDK library sources as a submodule for your app makes sense only if you need to edit facebook sources. Usually, you just want to use facebook api. If it is the case, just use code snippet above. You dont need to build facebookSDK library yourself, since someone already did that and hosted result .aar on the github, so you can just download this result .aar as if you would download regular .jar dependency.